# How to transfer files between FTP sites based on file names in a table using SSIS?

Tags: sql, ftp, ssis

I have a *source* FTP directory (3000 files) with files containing for example.

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
```

I want to only send 2000 files to the *destination* FTP only if the name of the files matches a value in my SQL database. Lets say we have a table with columns:

```
ID
Code (varchar)
```

In this table it displays like so:

```
ID     Code
1        1
2        2   
3        8
4        5
5        7
```

The Code column values corresponds to the name of the file name in the Source FTP directory.

So for example the Code column has values 1, 2 I want to send ONLY the files *`1.txt`* and *`2.txt`* to a new FTP destination.

How do I do this in a **`SSIS`** job or using **`T-SQL`**?

I can set up FTP tasks for receive and send, can I create a expression to deal with this?

Or does **`FileZilla`** have something that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Run a query to select all of the `CODE` values from your database into an `Object` variable, then use a `ForEach Loop` to loop through the values and move the files from one server to the other.

In your loop you can assign the `CODE` value to a separate `String` or `Int` variable, then use expressions to generate the filename(s)

Some walkthroughs:

http://coldlogics.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/using-ssis-to-dynamically-create-data-files-from-a-full-result-set/

http://www.select-sql.com/mssql/loop-through-ado-recordset-in-ssis.html